# From a Sudoku puzzle to a system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, sudoku

I created the following system of equations to solve a Sudoku puzzle.

[image]

It's easy to show that, if $a, b, c, \dots, i$ are distinct nonzero numbers, we have the following solution

$$S=\{(a_1,\dots,a_9) \mid a_i \in \{1,...,9\},a_i\neq a_j,\forall i\neq j\}$$

but how can I show this solution is unique?

Comment: If there are two equal numbers, the (Vandermonde-like) determinant is zero and the system can have no solution.

Comment: I would **not** write the system of $9$ polynomial equations in matrix form.

Comment: The solution is *not* unique. Any permutation of a solution is also a solution.

Comment: I know, that why i put the solution in S=${(a1,…,a9)∣ai∈{1,...,9},ai≠aj,∀i≠j}
S={(a1,…,a9)∣ai∈{1,...,9},ai≠aj,∀i≠j}$. But is that S the unique solution?

Comment: http://www.ams.org/notices/200706/tx070600708p.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer to your question. But I will note that you can achieve the same thing using just one Diophantine eqution. If you require that
$$ x_1^{100}+x_2^{100} + \ldots x_{9}^{100} = 1^{100} +2^{100} + \ldots 9^{100}$$
then in fact $\{x_1, x_2, \ldots , x_9\} = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ assuming you are looking for non-negative integer solutions. One can see first that it is impossible for any $x_i$ to exceed $9$ , since $10^{100}$ is in fact larger than the RHS of the equation. But if all the $x_i$ are at most $8$ , then the LHS is too small. So one of the variable equals $9$, say $x_9=9$. Subtract $9^{100}$ from both sides and proceed similarily to show to show that one variable equals $8$ and so on.